# Gradle sync error for go ethereum

Tags: android, go-ethereum

In the app's build.gradle file, I have included the maven central repository and added the dependency

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories
    {
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {

compile 'org.ethereum:geth:1.8.7'

}
```

But the Gradle sync failed with this error

```
Failed to resolve:  org.ethereum:geth:1.8.7
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Write below code :

```
 maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    google()
```

instead

```
 mavenCentral()
```

Comment: Solved..1.8.7 is not present in maven repository